Blazor: How to Trigger EventCallback on Value Change
So I have an Textinput and I want to bind it to the parent. But I can not invoke the EventCallback from the setter as it is async.
My input is this,
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@(Code)" 
    Label="Hex" 
    Variant="Variant.Outlined" >
</MudTextField>

And my property is this,
[Parameter]
public string Code
{
    get => _Code;
    set 
    {
        _Code = value;
       // Invoke the CodeChagned here so that the parent knows.
    }
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> CodeChanged { get; set; }

I need to update anoter filed in parent which is bind to the code property. But as I can not invoke this from setter and I do not have any button to have any clickable action to invoke. Then how can I do this?

Use the ValueChanged property that is exposed by the MudTextField. It accepts a EventCallback<T>. See the documentation: https://www.mudblazor.com/api/MudTextField%601#properties

Yes, But how can I invoke the CodeChanged? I am trying with ValueChanged but it does not do anything.

Try using the TextChanged property instead. It only captures the raw string value of the textbox, but I suppose that should be good enough for this use case. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYGobuwnGcMUfBJt

I had to do something like this TextChanged="@(async (newValue) => await InvokeChange(newValue))". Inside InvokeChange I am invoking the event Callback and it is working. Thank you very much.

I don't know the exact signature of InvokeChange, but if it's just some async function that accepts a string as a parameter you should just be able to pass it as a method group. TextChanged="@InvokeChange"

Hi @KhandakarRashedHassan Could you kindly check this thread? Maybe you are missing this line  <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />.

I see no reason why you can't Invoke it.
EventCallBacks have InvokeAsync.
I use your code everywhere in my blazor apps.
I completed your code.
[Parameter] // not sure why this is a parameter as it should be auto property... but it should not block invoking an EventCallBack
public string Code
{
    get => _Code;
    set 
    {
        _Code = value;
       
       CodeChanged.InvokeAsync(_Code); // like this...

       CodeChanged.InvokeAsync(value); // or like this...
    }
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> CodeChanged { get; set; }

